# How may I get a value from a Matlab container.map

Tags: matlab

I am inexperienced when it comes to Matlab and have been trying to utilize containers.map to make my code simpler. After some trial and error, I have been able to input values into my container but am struggling to find a good way to retrieve them.

To help illustrate my issue I have put an abridged version of my code below

```
Carbon = containers.Map({'AMod','TMod','PRat','SMod','ATS','SS','Density'}, ...
    {235.2,22.1,0.3,27,3700,36,1.8},'UniformValues',false);

Carbon('Q')=[15.23 12.10 1.12; 0.15 30.05 2.08; 20.23 0.05 5.87];

AModValue = values(Carbon,{'AMod'})
QValue    = values(Carbon,{'Q'})
```

When I run this code, I get results as follows

```
AModValue =
  1×1 cell array
    {[235.2]}
QValue =
  1×1 cell array
    {3×3 double}
```

My understanding is that all the useful information I have is contained in these 1x1 arrays.  Is there a good way to remove this data from these arrays and place them into their corresponding variables for later use?

In this example, I would want `AModValue` to be a double and `QValue` to be a 3x3 double.  Unfortunately, anything I can find on this issue seems to leave these values inside an array.

Comment: I thought that the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.html) is pretty good and complete. Did you not see the examples there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `values` for getting the value:

You may get the values directly from the map:

```
AModValue = Carbon('AMod')
QValue    = Carbon('Q')
```

---

Result:

```
AModValue =

  235.2000


QValue =

   15.2300   12.1000    1.1200
    0.1500   30.0500    2.0800
   20.2300    0.0500    5.8700
```

Comment: Wow. I cannot believe I missed that. Thank you!